# Notification sending from firebase console but its showing failed status but sending to all device is mark as completed

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-notifications

I have implemented push by firebase.

I'm sending notifications but I am getting status of "Failed". When I send notification to all devices it is marking as completed but I am still not getting messages in device.

Even when I send messages to single devices it will also show failed and will not receive notification on device.

The code is

```
private static final String TAG = "StartingAndroid";

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    //It is optional
    Log.e(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
    Log.e(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

    //Calling method to generate notification
    sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(),remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
}

//This method is only generating push notification
private void sendNotification(String title, String messageBody) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

[image: here is console]

Comment: Do you have to override onMessageReceived method? I thought firebase messaging would show a default notification.

Comment: there is no default notification

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your sender ID mismatched or you have entered incorrect project ID in your Application.

Comment: Yes actually i entered both of them incorrect but now problem is solved . thank you

Comment: Can you please tell me how you solved this? I have stucked since 3 days. @zaeemsattar

Answer (score 1):

Looking at logs, I think you are sending to specific devices via registration id but we see an error with mismatched sender id.Please check that these registration ids are valid and apply to the correct app.

Comment: yes thank you i just figured it out i was using wrong sender ID